# Creating a dashboard for Users - Help Needed for My Approach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have developed a web application in angular and In this application, users have a profile and There's a Dashboard in which users can add up to 4 elements/media like Images, Youtube Videos, Map, etc.

Users are able to change the layout/template just like **this**:

[image: Templates]

When Users Hover any of the boxes in these layouts, they should see a button that will open a Modal and gives them the ability to customize the content inside that box, for example If it's an Image they can change the Image or maybe choose a Map to be shown instead of the Image.

Users are also allowed to change the layout. The data of the Dashboard should be sent to Server each time it changes.

**What I need help with Is to see what's the best approach to do such thing in angular (1.x) since I haven't done such thing before!**

I'll appreciate it if you explain how can I do this or what's the best way to do it, or even share a **pen, fiddle or bin** if you know or have any!

Thanks.

Comment: These are generally called dashboards, not billboards.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I call it a Billboard, But if Dashboard is the correct word I will edit the text. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the first thing to understand is that you need to think in terms of separate components assembled into one application. So, in your particular case, each small box is going to be some type of component, for example `image-component`, `map-component` etc. It should receive the data it requires for its functionality from outside and shouldn't care where it came from. Then, once you created these small components, you going to need one `wrapper` component, that will hold these small functional components. This wrapper should be concerned only with UI presentation of smaller components and it's better if it knows nothing about the data required by box components, although it can act as a transmitter of the data. Based on your layout, you're going to have 4 such wrapper components on a page. You should use `services` to get the data each component requires. All presentation related logic, for example how many box components are currently rendered, should be placed into controllers. Finally, you're going to have one component that houses 4 wrapper components and this one top level component may act as communication channel between 4 wrappers components. It's better if you design each component as a close mechanism that receives some data, knows nothing about other components (unless the component is complex and includes child components) and performs limited functionality.

Comment: I see. I haven't had the chance to work with components introduced in angular 1.5 . And your approach seems to be promising! I will surely consider it and Thanks for sharing your thoughts!

Comment: You're welcome. This is kind of a question that is unwelcome on stackoverflow, but I know from my experience how hard it is to get the design right without any experience. You can treat `directives` as `components` before 1.5. And if you think I need to add some details so that it becomes acceptable answer let me know)

Comment: Yeah, I understand but as you mentioned it's better to know the best approaches instead of beginning with a wrong one you don't really know if it works or not! Thanks again. I think I'll wait for more answers before I begin to work on this since I have a day to think about it. If there weren't any more answers I will follow your approach of course and Accept yours as the Answer :)

Comment: nice approach to asking questions, I follow it myself)

Comment: @mamos98, it seems like no one else answered the question

Comment: Yes it seems no one's interested in this topic! :)

Comment: @mamos98, it's not the kind of question that's favored here. This kind of questions is usually left without an answer or closed as too broad